# Classes overloading operators function

Tags: c++, class, oop, operator-overloading

In my code below I'm having trouble with the function named normalize. Basically in this program, I input a fraction as 2 integers. This normalize function is supposed to make the denominator positive if it was input as a negative, and to make numerator & denominator positive if both are input as negative. And it also is supposed to convert the fraction into lowest terms form. So this works for some inputs but not others and I don't understand why.

Also in the main function, near the end of the end of it I try to test this normalize function and I don't know how to use oop principles to do this. I did it by just referring to member variables directly. How can I do this the oop way?

Here's my code for the class:

```
class Rational
{
public:
    Rational(int numer, int denom);//Initialize an object with 1 arguement for numerator and 1 for denominator
    Rational(int wholeNumber);//Initialize an object with 1 argument for numerator. Sets denominator to 1.
    Rational();//Initialize an object with 0 for numerator and 1 for denominator
    friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& outputStream, const Rational& number);//Overloading of insertion operator
    friend istream& operator >>(istream& inputStream, Rational& number);//Overloading of extraction operator
    friend bool operator ==(const Rational& number1, const Rational& number2);//Overloading of boolean "=="
    friend bool operator <(const Rational& number1, const Rational& number2);//Overloading of inequality sign
    friend bool operator <=(const Rational& number1, const Rational& number2);//Overloading of inequality sign
    friend bool operator >(const Rational& number1, const Rational& number2);//Overloading of inequality sign
    friend bool operator >=(const Rational numerator, const Rational& denominator);//Overloading of inequality sign
    friend const Rational operator +(const Rational& number1, const Rational& number2);//Overloading of + operator
    friend const Rational operator -(const Rational& number1, const Rational& number2);//Overloading of - operator
    friend const Rational operator *(const Rational number1, const Rational& number2);//Overloading of * operator
    friend const Rational operator /(const Rational& number1, const Rational& number2);//Overloading of / operator
    Rational normalize();//Normalizes the number so fraction is in lowest terms and denominator is positive
    int calcGCD(int numerator, int denominator);//Finds greatest common divisor between numerator and denominator
private:
    int numerator, denominator;
    };
```

And this is the normalizing function:

```
Rational Rational::normalize()
{
    if ((numerator > 0 && denominator < 0) || (numerator < 0 && denominator < 0))
    {
        denominator = -denominator;
        numerator = -numerator;
    }

    int gcd = calcGCD(numerator, denominator);
    numerator = numerator/gcd;
    denominator = denominator/gcd;

    return Rational(numerator, denominator);
}
```

Comment: That's not a question. It's your assignment. I didn't read all of it. Can you transform this post from a wall of text into a concise question about a piece of code? Thanks.

Comment: All I have are 2 basic questions which I explained in detail the the last 2 paragraphs. I just posted the assignment question and all my code for reference. I don't know how its possible to offer help without understanding the question and and how I've solved it using my code. What should I do? Read the last 2 paragraphs and tell me how I should make it more concise.

Comment: @JohnnySack http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The reason that you will post a more concise question is so I do not have to read these huge paragraphs!

Comment: Also, one question per question, please. One. Not two.

Comment: Made some changes.  You don't have to read the entire thing, just the very first part. I don't know how to explain my doubt shorter than this without giving enough info to get the context. Does this help?

Comment: For one, ask yourself what value `den` has when `(number.denominator != 0)` is *false* in your `operator <<` implementation. If your answer is "I dunno" you and the code are in agreement.

Comment: But when that condition is true, denominator is 0 and thats invalid. I thought  I shouldn't allow the program to set the denominator=0.

Comment: You're missing the point. When the condition is *false* `den` is **indeterminate**. You don't know *what* it is. When that output line dumps it via `<< den` the output is an utter wild-card (and technically invokes undefined behavior).  Btw, the same is true for your constructor. if `denom` is zero you never set the `denominator` member to *anything*. Thus it is also indeterminate. You say it works for some, but not for others. Your question should include sample inputs and outputs for **both**, and **all** code note directly required to reproduce the problem should not be in that post.

Comment: You may want to convert the comparison operators from friendly two parameter functions to one parameter member functions.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews why? it's recommended practice to use free functions when we are not modifying any objects.

Comment: @WhozCraig Hey so I've modified so that it goes --if den = 0, then output "denominator can't be zero. invalid." then exit(1). The next line then just assigns den to the denominator-- I did this in both the cases you mentioned. It still doesn't change the behaviour of the program. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few simple ways to handle normalize. Note I haven't really checked the OP's logic beyond removing the howlers. It looks good enough to answer the OP's question about how to use it properly in a OO environment.

## 1 Free-floating Function

This option is passed a [reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(C%2B%2B)) to a Rational and creates and returns a different Rational

```
Rational normalize(const Rational & in)
{
    // get values from Rational to work on so we don't have to keep getting  
    // them over and over
    int num = in.getNumerator(); 
    int den = in.getDenominator();
        // numerator and denominator are public, so getters aren't strictly necessary,
        // but data members should always be private unless given a damn good reason 
        // and probably not even then.  If you're going to learn, might as well learn 
        // to do it right, go private and use getters.

    if (den < 0)
    { // if the denominator is negative, flip the signs of both den and num
        den *= -1;
        num *= -1;
    }

    int gcd = calcgcd(num, den); //grabbing gcd and string in temp
    // note I changed the name of the function. int gcd = gcd() is in poor taste even 
    // if it does compile, and the function should state what it does. 
    // It doesn't GCD, it calculates GCD.
    num = num / gcd;
    den = den / gcd;

    return Rational(num, den); // create and return a new Rational. 
                               // Compiler should be smart enough to avoid copying 
}
```

Using it:

```
Rational notNormalized(245, 49);
Rational normalized = normalize(notNormalized);
```

## 2 Non-destructive Method

In this variant, a Rational uses itself to make a different, normalized Rational.

Because this is a class method, its declaration needs to be added to the class.

```
Rational normalize() const;
```

The `const` tag means the Rational object is not changed in any way by using this method. Trying to change the object inside the normalize method will cause a compiler error.

and then the implementation:

```
Rational Rational::normalize() const
{
    // get copies of numerator and denominator so we don't damage this Rational  
    int num = numerator;
    int den = denominator;
    if (den < 0)
    { 
        den *= -1;
        num *= -1;
    }

    int gcd = calcgcd(num, den);
    num = num / gcd;
    den = den / gcd;

    return Rational(num, den); 
}
```

Using it:

```
Rational notNormalized(245, 49);
Rational normalized = notNormalized.normalize();
```

## 3 Modifying Method

In this variant, a Rational normalizes itself

Because this is a class method, its declaration needs to be added to the class.

```
Rational normalize();
```

and then the implementation:

```
void Rational::normalize()
{
    if (denominator < 0)
    { 
        denominator *= -1;
        numerator *= -1;
    }
    int gcd = calcgcd(numerator, denominator);
    numerator /= gcd;
    denominator /= gcd;
}
```

Using it:

```
Rational soonToBeNormalized(245, 49);
soonToBeNormalized.normalize();
```

## ADDENDUM

To get a question answered quickly, cut the question down to the absolute minimum. The class definition, the normalize function, and "How do I make this normalize function work with this Rational class?" would have sufficed. The remainder was chaff that sucked the interest and will to help out of people.

Comment: Great answer!! Since we're learning about classes,I chose your 2nd method and it worked!!! In the normalize function declaration and definition heading, why don't you have to list the parameter types? And in the return part of normalize function definition, why do you have to put --return Rational(num, den)-- because the function is already the class type, wouldn't it return a value or object of that same type?

Comment: A method returns what you want it to return. The only methods that don't are the constructor (technically doesn't return anything, it just formats a block a memory provided to it) and the destructor (just cleans up before the memory is released, so there is nothing to return). Otherwise say you have a method that performs the division implied by the rational. How does it get the result out to the caller? The return statement. eg: `double Rational::divide() {return (double)numerator/(double)denominator}`. Do a bit more reading to get functions figured out, because it's too broad to cover here.

Comment: @JohnnySack What you've done in your modified question above is a  mix of 2 and 3. You directly modify the calling object, and then return a copy. Option 3 doesn't need to return anything, because the object **is** the result. Option 2 needs to return a brand new Rational because it does not modify the source rational. By the way, don't modify questions to suit the answer because it destroys the flow of the question and answer format.